# Failed to resolve SessionToken with media3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-media3

I'm trying to use media3 and for that I'm following the tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/playing-in-background

However when I run my code I have the following error on this line:

```
val sessionToken = SessionToken(this, ComponentName(this, PlaybackService::class.java))
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to resolve SessionToken for ComponentInfo{com.example.euphonia/PlaybackService}. Manifest doesn't declare one of either MediaSessionService, MediaLibraryService, MediaBrowserService or MediaBrowserServiceCompat. Use service's full name.
```

Things are already properly declared in my manifest as shown in my tutorial

```
<service
    android:name="PlaybackService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced this runtime error and it seems like your service declaration is the culprit: if your `PlaybackService` class is in a package (from the error it seems like it is) your service declaration should take that into consideration:

```
<service
    android:name=".PlaybackService"
    ...
```

or using its fully qualified name

```
<service
   android:name="com.example.euphonia.PlaybackService"
   ...
```

Comment: I already have it in my build.gradle

Comment: You're right, that's not the problem. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: My error was indeed related to that, in my case I was missing the package declaration in my PlaybackService class, thanks a lot